# Extending The Gauss-Lucas Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

How broad is the class of functions with hulls of roots containing the derivative's roots?

We know from the Gauss-Lucas theorem that the above statement holds for all complex polynomials. The most common proof of the theorem goes something like this:

Let $P(z)$ be polynomial. Factor as $P(z) = \alpha\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n} (z-a_i)$ where $a_1, ..., a_n$ are the roots of $P$.

If $P(\omega) = P'(\omega)$ then $\omega=a_{i}$ for some $i \Rightarrow$ done

Assume, then, that $P'(\omega) = 0$ but $P(\omega) \neq 0$.

Via a logarithmic derivative, we get $$\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-a_i}$$

And so $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\omega-a_i} = sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\bar{\omega}-\bar{a_i}}{|\omega - a_i|^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|\omega-a_i|^2}\right)\bar{\omega}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|\omega-a_i|^2}\bar{a_i}$$

Taking conjugates, we get $$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{ca}{|\omega-a_i|^2} where \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{c}{|\omega-a_i|^2}=1$$

Q.E.D.

The above proof also works, I believe, for any function whose Taylor series can be factored s.t. that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-a_i}$ converges.

Can we say something about Laurent series? And are there broader meaningful classes of functions $f$ s.t. the roots of $f'$ lie in the convex hull of the roots of f? What's the broadest such class?

Comment: for entire functions genus zero works and with slightly more work exponential type zero, but something like $(z^2-1)^me^{az}, a >0, m$ large enough shows it doesn't work there, however for conjugate invariant entire functions with real zeroes, Laguerre theorem shows that the result almost extends up to order $2-\epsilon$ in the sense that the critical points are real and separated by the zeroes of $f$ though they may not quite be in the convex hull as the example given shows; for rational functions I would check Bochner-walsh theorem for various generalizations of Gauss-Lucas there